# Php, I cant access inherited private variables not even with reflection

Tags: php, reflection

```
class A
{
    private $a;
}

class B extends A
{
    function __construct()
    {
        (new \ReflectionClass($this))->getProperty('a')->setAccessible(true);
        echo $this->a;
    }
}

(new B());
```

this should work, altough it triggers an exception: "property a doesnt exists". Many articles says Reflection is the sollution

Comment: Reading the [Notes in the PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperty.php) should help, specifically that posted by dohpaz42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the `ReflectionClass` an instance of `B`, which doesn't have access to `$a`. What you need is to pass it an instance of `A` instead. This should help clarify what you need to do here

```
class A
{
    private $a = 'Bob';
}

class B extends A
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $instance = new A();
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($instance);
        $property = $reflection->getProperty('a');
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        echo $property->getValue(new A());
    }
}

(new B());
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/X2TX6)

Answer (score 1):

> I cant access **inherited private variables** not even with reflection

Private properties and methods belong to a class they were declared.
They're not accessible from the derived class unless you override them